# Can't detect corner in thermal image with openCV function findChessboardCorners

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

as i mention in title, i can't detect corner of these images using findChessboardCorners function.my image capture from an IR-camera with resolution 640x480? Is my picture enough contrast? Due to limited condition so I can't capture the chessboard at a larger scale? Someone can fingure out to me what's wrong?

this is my code:
import cv2

```
CHECKERBOARD = (4, 4)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objpoints = []

imgpoints = []


objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0] * CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0, :, :2] = np.mgrid[0 : CHECKERBOARD[0], 0 : CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
prev_img_shape = None

images = glob.glob("./images2/*.jpg")
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    # If desired number of corners are found in the image then ret = true

    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(
        gray,
        CHECKERBOARD,
        cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH
        + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK
        + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE,
    )
    print(ret)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        # refining pixel coordinates for given 2d points.
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHECKERBOARD, corners2, ret)

    cv2.imshow("img", gray)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and one of my images like that[image]:

Comment: may or may not be the reason but the intensity difference between white and black is so low. you may need to figure it out firstly

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thanks for your advice, but It isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried findChessboardCornersSB? Maybe a different result

Comment: you mean 3x3...

Comment: size for chessboard must be larger than (2,2)